# XCode error 'YogaKit.modulemap' not found

Tags: ios, reactjs, swift, iphone, react-native

I have an error when I try build my project.

fatalerror: module map file '`/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap`' not found

what can I do?

Comment: Clean derived data? How did you import YogaKit? SPM? CocoaPods? Carthage? Manually?

Comment: i cleaned derived data but problem continue. i import with cocapods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try necessary steps only but if still not work than Please try everything including necessary and unnecessary steps.

1 - Not important(Package.json)

```
"dependencies": {
 "react": "17.0.1",
 "react-native": "0.64.2"
}
```

2 - necessary

```
  use_flipper!()
  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
        installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config| config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] =  "arm64"
        end
  end
```

OR

```
 use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings["ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH"] = "NO"
          end
      end
  end
```

3 - Add `arm64` under `Architectures->Excluded Architectures`

4 - Add a swift file under your project, can be empty, can be `BridgingFile.swift`(nothing special in it), this will trigger a bridging header. **Wallah, here you go**.

[image]

ref : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29605#issuecomment-861783673

Comment: I think issue is with Apple silicon. That is the reason it worked! If you run as Rosetta that will work to.

Comment: Not working for me.